# Can a WSGI application tell the web server serving it to send its default HTTP 404 error page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi, uwsgi

I have a bare WSGI application in a module called `app` (app.py) that looks like this:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    path = environ['PATH_INFO']
    if path == '/':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b'<p>It works!</p>\n']
    elif path == '/foo':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b'<p>Hello World</p>\n']
    else:
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b'<p>Page Not Found</p>\n']
```

I am serving this app using nginx + uwsgi with this configuration.

```
nifty:/www# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myhost
server {
        listen 8080;
        root /www/myhost;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name myhost;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I start uwsgi with this command:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:9090 --module app
```

The app behaves as expected:

```
debian:~# curl -i http://myhost:8080/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 13:05:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

<p>It works!</p>
debian:~# curl -i http://myhost:8080/foo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 13:05:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

<p>Hello World</p>
debian:~# curl -i http://myhost:8080/bar
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 13:05:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

<p>Page Not Found</p>
```

However, I am not happy with the HTTP 404 'Page Not Found' response. I would want that when my WSGI app wants to send HTTP 404 response, the default HTTP 404 error page of nginx is sent to the client.

Here is how the default HTTP 404 response of nginx looks like. Note the response below is from the default virtual host (not the `myhost` virtual host used in the examples above). The default virtual host doesn't have any WSGI application and hence you are able to see the default HTTP 404 error page of nginx in the output below.

```
debian:~# curl -i http://localhost:8080/bar
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 13:06:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.4</center>
</body>
</html>
debian:~#
```

Is there a way for my WSGI application to tell the web server serving it to send its HTTP 404 response to the client?

Note:

1. I want the solution to be web-server agnostic, i.e. I shouldn't have to hard-code the web server's HTTP 404 page in my code or template, or I shouldn't have to read some HTML that is very specific to nginx. The solution should work on nginx or any other web-server like Apache, lightttpd, etc.
2. I am aware that one should be using WSGI framework to do actual web development. I am probably going to settle for bottle.py but before doing so, I am trying to understand the capabilities and limitations of WSGI so that I know what is going on behind the scenes when I use bottle.

Comment: You could redirect the browser to a different URL *not* served by the WSGI application, then have the server respond to that with a 404. But otherwise, anything that the WSGI Server handles should produce a valid WSGI response. There are no options to tell the WSGI server to produce a 404 page for that status, not as a part of the standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your comment. If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting me to send an HTTP 301 redirect to a non-existing URL in my server to the client. Am I right? This seems to produce a different behaviour (send HTTP 301 redirect to the client first, then send HTTP 404 error) whereas I wanted to simply send an HTTP 404 error response. If you can confirm I am correct so far, then I can probably take a decision to give up the idea of trying to make the web-server send an HTTP 404 page and generate my own HTTP 404 responses from the WSGI application.

Comment: Yes, the WSGI app would produce a 301, the client would then make *another* request to a URL not handled by the WSGI app, which then results in a 404. Not ideal, but I've seen it applied. A good WSGI framework lets you handle 404 error pages at the application level; simply raise a special exception or return a special response object and the framework will return a HTML page and 404 status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments section, the answer seems to be:

No!

Answer (score 0):

See if uWSGI in combination with nginx supports:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_intercept_errors

If it doesn't support it with its native protocol, you may have to run uWSGI in HTTP accept mode and use normal nginx proxy mode via HTTP. Then you could definitely use it.

Either way, get on IRC on the #uwsgi channel and ask unbit. Likely they will add the feature before you can finish the conversation. He is like that.